# how to send kubectl logs output over mail in azure devops

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops

I have an azuredevops build job to get the log of a deployment pod.

command:  `kubectl logs deployment/myapp`

I am getting the output in the summary page of azure devops pipeline, but the same I want to send a team with a log as an attachment. I am not getting any option in azure devops for that

Comment: As you mentioned, you want to send the log to the team members? Based on my experience, there hasn't such option exists(can send notification, but without log). what about consider to use additional script to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your k8s log (pods) will gone after the pods has been terminated (although you can somehow keep it for a little while). For debug purpose or any other purpose you want, you need to `Centralized logging` your k8s log (use some tools: filebeat, fluentd, fluent-bit to forward your k8s log to elasticsearch).

EX: Some software (tools) for `Centralized logging` Elasticsearch, Graylog, ...

https://www.elastic.co/fr/what-is/elk-stack

And then you can save, export, analyze your log ... You can do anythings you want with your stored k8s log.

Hope this may help you, guy!

Edit: I use GCP as cloud solution and in GCP, by default, they will use fluentd to forward your k8s log to store in `Logging`. And the `Logging` has feature `Export`, I think you can search somethings similar to `Logging` in your cloud solution: Azure

Comment: but in my case i was looking for some option in my build pipeline task to generate and send the pods logs whenever need to get..